# Interpretation Ln Lognormal (DV) Variable in MLE Model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, lognormal-distribution

Say you have a lognormal variable and you want to use it after a natural logarithmic transformation as the dependent variable (DV) in a multiple linear least squares model. You can interpret the outcome as a percentage change in the DV given a unit change in the independent variable.

Now my question is, what if it wasn't a least squares model but the parameter estimate came from a maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) based model. How is the outcome estimate interpreted? It is a logged version of y, so does the percentage interpretation come into play or do you just call it  log(y), and can the estimate be backtransformed to the original pre-natural logarithmic transformed scale?